# Cantor's diagonal diagram

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that the union of countable sets is countable. I know that we can we list each set $s_n$ horizontally like this: (I know that this has already been proved here before)
$$s_{11}, s_{12}, s_{13} ...$$

$$s_{21}, s_{22}, s_{23} ...$$
$$s_{31}, s_{32}, s_{33} ...$$
$$...$$

We can count the the elements diagonally with the $n$th column having $n$th elements. I know that if we count "horizontally" we might never finish as there are infinite elements. However, would we not face the same problem if our grid is a square and the biggest diagonal would have the same number of elements than the first row.

I do not understand why are we not considering the case of the biggest diagonal (that might have the same number of elements than the first row and we agreed that starting with the first row will cause a lot of problems).

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Each row and column is infinite. So the concept of square doesn't apply. There is no longest diagonal. Each diagonal in the proof is finite.

Comment: @user4894 Thank you, I understand it better now (concept of squares when there are infinite elements is meaningless). But would there still not be some diagonals with infinite elements if there are infinite number of countable sets?

Comment: Imagine that there are infinitely many rows and each row has infinitely many columns. Now when you do the "snaking diagonals" proof, the first diagonal contains 1 element. The second contains 2; the third contains 3; and so forth. You can see that the n-th diagonal contains exactly n elements. Each diag is finite.

Comment: Each upward slanting diagonal is finite. Each downward slanting diagonal is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing, that you do not have to get to an end, when counting.

The point in the definition of a set beeing 'countable' is, that you eventually get to every element at some point, even when there are infinite many to count. Where you can not get to an end, anyways.

So you are in a position to say element $x$ occours at position $y$.
If you would not count 'diagonally' and just horizontal, you would never get to the element $s_{21}$ for example, or many other. Because you would never stop counting the elements of the set $\{s_{11}, s_{12}, s_{13},\dotso\}$

But you could tell me when you get to the element $s_{314,15926}$ when counted diagonally.

Comment: Thank you, it is very clear to me now. But @user4894 mentions that there are no infinite diagonals, But would it not result in diagonals with infinite elements if there are infinitely many countable sets?

Comment: No, there are no diagonals with infinite elements. But the number of elements in the diagonals are not bounded. Maybe you confuse this? As you can see the diagonals contain 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and so on elements. These are finite, but not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A set $X$ is countable if you can find a counting scheme such that it doesn't miss any element of $X$ i.e. for any arbitrary element $x\in X$, you always come up with a token that fits $x$. It doesn't matter that the scheme succeeds in counting all elements of $X$. Cantor's diagonal scheme does it beautifully.